# Proving new features theoretically help learning

Tags: classification, mathematical-statistics, convergence, feature-engineering, mutual-information

I've been recently working with feature construction. I was wondering, whether how one would go about proving, that given a standard classification setting, a new feature can improve a classifier's performance.

I know this is a very general description, here is my take at this:

1. Compute mutual information between the new feature and the target class
2. If it is higher than e.g., average mutual information of existing features, this indicates potential for better learning

Are there any existing proofs of such statements?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/374234/more-features-less-f-score/374236#374236

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/267108/how-can-adding-a-feature-reduce-a-models-performance

Comment: These two questions might help you to understand this issue in more detail. I decided to comment instead of answering, because I cannot provide a formal proof you are looking for.